# Change value in array using yq from mike farah

Tags: bash, yaml

In my yaml file I have this persons array (it only has one element always)

```yaml
persons:
  - name:  mario
    version: 1.0.0
    city: Madrid
```

how can I replace city to any other value using yq ?

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
yq -i '.persons[0].city = "Barcelona"' yourfile.yaml
```

replacing “Barcelona” and `yourfile.yaml` as appropriate. This replaces the value of `city` inside the first element of the `persons` array (or creates it if there is none).

Comment: Parametrized: `newcity=Barcelona yq '.persons[0].city = env(newcity)'`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you dont know the exact index, but know the `name` of the object you could try this:

```
yq -i '.persons[] |= select(.name == "mario").city = "Barcelona"' yourfile.yaml
```

works in `yq version 4.25.2`

UPDATE based on comments (Kusalananda), for versions 4.3x and 4.4x you need to use the following:

```
yq4407 -i '.persons |= map(select(.name == "mario").city = "Barcelona")' city.yaml
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working with Mike's `yq`, v4.40.1.  It empties the list.

Comment: If you want to change all `mario`'s cities to Barcelona, you could use `.persons |= map(select(.name == "mario").city = "Barcelona")`.

Comment: @Kusalananda thx for checking in latest version!